# Querying iota from browser or non-full-node

Tags: iri-node

Do nodes typically allow you to query them for transactions?  Is this something that is blocked by default?  It seems like it would increase communication in the network, but I understand that this could weigh down nodes.

Comment: I cannot speak for 'typical' nodes, but is is an option whether you want to accept API requests from everyone or only from localhost. In the latter case, the only thing other neighbors can do is push transactions and ask to get pushed other transactions they miss. Nodes who are not listed as a neighbor cannot request anything in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRI has a REST API. Therefore, you are able to access it via JavaScript, also from a web browser. You are probably looking for the [findTransaction Endpoint](https://docs.iota.org/docs/iri/0.1/references/api-reference#findtransactions).
You can also query full-nodes from your host machine via your favorite programming language. [Here is a list of public full-nodes](https://www.tangle-nodes.com/?sorts[load]=1&sorts[tls]=-1). Some full-nodes are not available for the public. These nodes are not accessible from the outside on the REST API port or they have some kind of IP filter.